# Parallelize a script in multiple fasta files

Tags: parallel-processing, bioinformatics, biopython

I need to run a simple script on a large amount of fasta files. It is very simple: I just need to add some information to the header of the files.

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
from Bio import SeqIO
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def header(dirname):
    with open('output.fasta', 'w') as output:
        for file in os.listdir(dirname):
            if file == "output.fasta":
                    continue
            seq = SeqIO.parse(file, 'fasta')
            ortog = Path(file).stem
            for record in seq:
                record.description = ortog
                SeqIO.write(record, output, 'fasta')
```

I am trying to parallelize the script in python to optimize the time since I will have to do this a few times, but I am having some difficulties with how to use the multiprocessing package. Can anyone give me directions on how to make this parallelization work?

I'm getting the error "TypeError: map() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'"

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    with mp.Pool(4) as pool:
        pool.map(header, args=(dirname))
    finish_time = time.perf_counter()
    print("Program finished in {} seconds - using multiprocessing".format(finish_time-start_time))
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the argument to your function like this:

```
    pool.map(header, dirname)
```

`args` is part of `Process` spawning in python multiprocessing. `pool` is a convenient way to do data parallelism. Single argument can only be passed in Pool but it can be a list.

[See more](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Answer (score 0):

> `map(func, iterable[, chunksize])` 
> A parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function (it supports only one iterable argument though, for multiple iterables see starmap()). It blocks until the result is ready.
> This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive integer.              Note that it may cause high memory usage for very long iterables. Consider using imap() or imap_unordered() with explicit chunksize option for better efficiency.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map